# Differentiating the Norm of a Matrix Vector Product

Tags: linear-algebra

How is it that $D_x(||Ax-b||^2)$ evaluates to $2A^T||Ax-b||$?  Wouldn't it just result in X being a vector of 1s not of zeros?

Ex. A matrix $(1,2)(3,4)$ times a vector $(x1,x2)$ once differentiated gives the same matrix times $(1,1)$.  That gives the matrix $(3,3)(7,7)$.  I'm sure this is wrong but not sure why.  Is it as simple as it being an order of operations issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\|Ax-b\|^2 = (x'A'-b')(Ax-b) =\sum_j \Bigl(\sum_i x_i a_{ji}-b_j\Bigr)^2.$$

Now differentiate with respect to $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and stack the result into a vector and you have $2A'(Ax-b) \neq 2A'\|Ax-b\|$.

Comment: Doesn't the first equality ignore the fact that this this is the square of a norm?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: I have added a part to my question just to clarify my mistaken idea.