# Intuition beyond differentiating the Norm of a Matrix Vector Product

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

There is [very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762380/differentiating-the-norm-of-a-matrix-vector-product), the problem is that I do not understand the answer:)

Suppose you have a function $\,\,\,f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left\lVert Ax-b \right\rVert_2^2$, where $x \in R^n$. 
Gradient of the function $\nabla_xf(x)=A^T(Ax - b)$.

*Could you please explain what is the intuition beyond calculating $\nabla_xf(x)$ result?*

As I know $\nabla_xf(x)=\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{df}{dx_1} \\ 
\frac{df}{dx_2} \\
... \\
\frac{df}{dx_n}
\end{bmatrix}$

So everything I can do with my math background is to suppose $x \in R^2$ and pass all necessary coordinates to the function:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left\lVert
\begin{bmatrix}i_x & j_x \\ i_y & j_y\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}
- \begin{bmatrix}b_1 \\ b_2\end{bmatrix}
\right\rVert_2^2 =
\\[1ex]
\frac{1}{2} \left\lVert
  \begin{bmatrix}
    i_xx_1 + j_xx_2 - b_1 \\ i_yx_1 + j_yx_2-b_2
  \end{bmatrix}
\right\rVert_2^2 =
\\[1ex]
\frac{1}{2} \bigl((i_xx_1 + j_xx_2 - b_1)^2 + (i_yx_1 + j_yx_2-b_2)^2\bigr)
$$
Then I multiple all the stuff and calculate partial derivatives of the function. It's clear from my results that $\nabla_xf(x)=A^T(Ax - b)$ but my method takes up to 15 minutes. Is there any intuition to avoid calculating all the stuff?

Comment: Finally got the intuition by my own. Will add the answer in 30 minutes

Answer (score 1):

To catch the intuition beyond the way that gradient of the function $\,f(v) = \left\lVert Av-b \right\rVert_2^2$ is calculated, let look what the function represents graphicaly at $R^2$ space:

At the graph below, we have vectors ***v*** and ***b*** that represent respective vectors at the formulla $f(v)$. Vector ***Av*** represent transformation of ***v*** with the matrix ***A***.

[image]

### Decomposing formula to more simple concepts

Partial derivative by $x$: $\frac{df(v)}{dx}$ means how much $\left\lVert Av-b \right\rVert_2^2$ change with the smalest change of $X$ coordinate of vector ***v***. We can decompose $\frac{df(v)}{dx}$ into more simple concepts:

$$
\frac{df(v)}{dx} = \frac{dAv}{dx}\frac{df(v)}{dAv}
$$

The same for all othe directions. So we can write that:

$$
\nabla_{f(v)} = \nabla_{Av/dx} \nabla_{df(v)/dAv}
$$

### Calculating $\nabla_{df(v)/dAv}$

Let say $A \bar v = \bar a$. 
$\bar a = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ .. \\ a_n \end{bmatrix}$. 
$\bar b = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ .. \\ b_n \end{bmatrix}$. 
$\frac{df(v)}{dAv}$ derivative into $i_{th}$ direction equals to:
$$
\lim \limits_{\delta_i \to 0} \frac{
\left\lVert
\Biggl(\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ .. \\ .. \\ .. \\ a_n \end{bmatrix} -
\begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ .. \\ .. \\ .. \\ b_n \end{bmatrix}\Biggr) +
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ .. \\ \delta_i \\ .. \\ a_n \end{bmatrix}
\right\rVert_2^2 - \left\lVert a - b \right\rVert_2^2
}{\delta_i} = 
\lim \limits_{\delta_i \to 0} \frac{
 (a_1 - b_1)^2 + (a_2 - b_2)^2 + .. + (a_i - b_i + \delta_i)^2 + .. + (a_n - b_n)^2 - \left\lVert a - b \right\rVert_2^2
}{\delta_i} = 
\lim \limits_{\delta_i \to 0} \frac{
 (a_1 - b_1)^2 + (a_2 - b_2)^2 + .. + (a_i - b_i)^2 +2\delta_i(a_i - b_i) + \delta_i^2 + .. + (a_n - b_n)^2 - \left\lVert a - b \right\rVert_2^2
}{\delta_i} = 
\lim \limits_{\delta_i \to 0} \frac{
 (a_1 - b_1)^2 + (a_2 - b_2)^2 + .. + (a_i - b_i)^2 + .. + (a_n - b_n)^2 + 2\delta_i(a_i - b_i) + \delta_i^2 - \left\lVert a - b \right\rVert_2^2
}{\delta_i} =
\lim \limits_{\delta_i \to 0} \frac{
 \left\lVert a - b \right\rVert_2^2 +  2\delta_i(a_i - b_i) + \delta_i^2 - \left\lVert a - b \right\rVert_2^2  
}{\delta_i} =  
\lim \limits_{\delta_i \to 0} \frac{ 2\delta_i(a_i - b_i) + \delta_i^2}{\delta_i} =  
\lim \limits_{\delta_i \to 0} \frac{2\delta_i(a_i - b_i)}{\delta_i} = 2(a_i - b_i) 
$$

So $\nabla_{df(v)/dAv}$ in direction *i* equals to $2(a_i - b_i)$.

Due $\bar a = Av$:

$$
\nabla_{df(v)/dAv} = 2 \begin{bmatrix}a_1 - b_1 \\ a_2 - b_2 \\ .. \\ a_n - b_n\end{bmatrix} = 2 (Av - b)
$$

### Calculating $\frac{dAv}{dx_i}$

$\frac{dAv}{dx}$ is the vector that measure of how transformed vector ***Av*** will change when we add $\delta_x$ to X coordinate of vector ***v***. In other words:

$$
\frac{dAv}{dx} = 
A\begin{bmatrix} v_x + \delta_x \\ v_y \end{bmatrix}
- A\begin{bmatrix} v_x \\ v_y \end{bmatrix}
$$

The same for Y direction:

$$
\frac{dAx}{dy} = 
A\begin{bmatrix} v_x \\ v_y + \delta_y \end{bmatrix}
- A\begin{bmatrix} v_x \\ v_y \end{bmatrix}
$$

To figure out what is $\frac{dAv}{dx}$, let think about what is matrix-vector product.

$$
Av = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & .. & a_{1n} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & .. & a_{2n} \\
  ..     & ..     & .. & ..     \\
  a_{n1} & a_{n2} & .. & a_{nn}  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1 \\ x_2 \\ .. \\ x_n
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1a_{11} & x_2a_{12} & .. & x_na_{1n} \\
  x_1a_{21} & x_2a_{22} & .. & x_na_{2n} \\
  .. & .. & .. & .. \\
  x_1a_{n1} & x_2a_{n2} & .. & x_na_{nn} \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\\[1ex]
= 
x_1 \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} \\ a_{21} \\ .. \\ a_{n1} \end{bmatrix} + 
x_2 \begin{bmatrix} a_{12} \\ a_{22} \\ .. \\ a_{n2} \end{bmatrix} + 
.. +
x_n \begin{bmatrix} a_{1n} \\ a_{2n} \\ .. \\ a_{nn} \end{bmatrix} =
\text{linear combination of column vectors of matrix A}
$$

From formula above it should be clear that partial derivative of ***Av*** in direction $x_i$ should equal to $i_{th}$ column vector of matrix ***A***.

### Calculating gradient for vector Av: $\nabla_{Av}$

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & .. & a_{1n} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & .. & a_{2n} \\
  ..     & ..     & .. & ..     \\
  a_{n1} & a_{n2} & .. & a_{nn}  
\end{bmatrix}
\\[1ex]
\frac{dAv}{dx_i} = \begin{bmatrix}
  a_{1i} \\ a_{2i} \\ .. \\ a_{ni}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

From two facts above its clear that:
$$
\nabla_{Av} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{dAv}{dx_1} \\
  \frac{dAv}{dx_2} \\
  .. \\
  \frac{dAv}{dx_n} 
\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{21} & .. & a_{n1} \\
  a_{12} & a_{22} & .. & a_{n2} \\
  .. & .. & .. & .. \\
  a_{1n} & a_{2n} & .. & a_{nn} \\
\end{bmatrix} = A^T
$$

### Final result

$$
\nabla_{f(v)} = \nabla_{Av/dx} \nabla_{df(v)/dAv} = 2A^T(Av - b)
$$

If $\,f(v) = \frac{1}{2} \left\lVert Av-b \right\rVert_2^2$, than $\, \nabla_{f(v)} = A^T(Av - b)$